# Windows 10 to Centos7 Remote Desktop

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, centos7, remote-desktop, xrdp

My desktop computer is running Windows 10.  I have created a virtual computer using Oracle VM Virtual Box that runs Centos7.  In my Virtual Box settings I have changed the network adapter to Bridged Adapter.  Everything starts correctly when the vm comes up.  I then installed xrdp and tigervnc-server through epel.  I have both xrdp and tigervnc services running.  However when I try to remote desktop from Windows 10 to my virtual box, it can not connect.  I can open a cmd window on Windows 10 and ping my ip address.  The only thing that sticks out to me is that when I tried to enable the xrdp service, it states that it is not a native service.  It still starts and attaches to port 3390.  I changed this from 3389 after reading some tickets on stackoverflow.

```
xrdp.service is not a native service, redirecting to /sbin/chkconfig.
Executing /sbin/chkconfig xrdp on
```

Is this the firewall biting me?  What did I miss?

TIA

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so it was the firewall that was biting me along with VM Virtual Box.  In order to do remote desktop to a vm in Virtual Box, you must download an install VM Virtual Box extension pack.  That will allow you to enable rdp under the display tab in settings.  I also had to add the following to the CentOs firewall

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port 3389/tcp
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port 3350/tcp
```

Finally, I had to make sure that my vncpasswd was set to the same value as my CentOs login password.  Otherwise it would not allow me to log in.